# Keyboard lags after grafics card change

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

A workstation (lenovo - windows 10) received a new graphics card (Quadro P400 - 2 GB GDDR5 - PCIe 3.0 x16 Low-Profile - 3 x Mini DisplayPort) to allow the user to plug in three screens. Since this update, the keyboard lags when typing sometimes. This means, the punched keys are not shown on the screen, but appear a few seconds later.

Until now I was not able to reproduce the problem, which does occur on a daily basis but not always.

How can i takle this problem?

Comment: Did you update the Lenovo BIOS (UEFI) for this machine?  Have you got the latest Video driver?

Comment: Latest video driver is installed, I'll post again after I've udpated the bios